Read and write float type between two threads in C#
I have two threads and a float-type value has been shared between these threads. A float-type value is written on Thread1 and reads by Thread2.
Thread1 and Thread2 start at the same time.
 private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536 * 8;
 private float _readWriteValue = 0;
 private bool _stop = false;

 private void Thread1()
 {
     Random ran = new Random();
     while (!_stop)
     {
         _readWriteValue = ran. Next(1, 100);
     }
 }
 private void Thread2()
 {
     while (!_stop)
     {
         float[] BufferData  = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
         for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
         {
             BufferData[i] = _readWriteValue;
         }
         ProcessMethod(BufferData);
     }
 }

 private void ProcessMethod(float[] data)
 {
     // Do Something
 }

So, When I check BufferData, it fills by only one number. for example, the BufferData fills only with 22. It seems when _readWriteValue goes to for loop in Thread2, has been locked and Thread1 can not write a new value in it.
I'm trying to find out what is the solution. I'm trying by lock, Monitor, and ConcurrentQueue, but every time I get the same results. BufferData is filled by only one number.
Do I have a wrong understanding of the multi-threading?
What should I do?


Can't replicate your issue. https://i.sstatic.net/TpcAltmJ.png

Since it was cut of in the screenshot the print line is Console.WriteLine($"Distinct Values (5 or more): {string.Join(", ", data.Distinct().Take(5))}");

and I would recommend using Interlocked class - to set value Interlocked.Exchange - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=net-8.0#system-threading-interlocked-exchange(system-int64@-system-int64) and to read value Interlocked.Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.read?view=net-8.0#system-threading-interlocked-read(system-int64@)

What output did you expect?

I expected Every index of buffer to have a different value.

Even with only a buffer of 10, still cant reproduce it: https://i.sstatic.net/G0aSy9QE.png

The problem is that Thread2 might finish before Thread1 even got started, or as in your case maybe just ran the loop once.

why "every index"? you realise random could return the same value twice? you realise filling the array could fill more then one element before a new random value is set?

I got the same number every time. Could it be because of the speed of the processor?

Since readWriteValue is not volatile, the reading thread may also see a stale value.

@AlirezaIzadimehr there's no locking in this code. Threads run whenever they're scheduled by the OS, which means there's no guarantee that both will be running on different cores at the same time. Random number generation is a lot slower than reading a float too, which means Thread2 is "faster" than Thread1 and will read the same time multiple times before Thread1 had a chance to create a new value. The CPU itself may use optimizations to assign multiple buffer locations "at once" because nothing told it the value can change. There's no lock, no volatile keyword

ConcurrentQueue no, if ConcurrentQueue is used properly there won't be any issue. Calling TryDequeue in a tight loop will waste CPU if there's nothing to read but won't produce ghost data. Duplicates will be produced by a loop that doesn't check the result of TryDequeue before advancing the index

Alireza when you say that the BufferData is filled by only one number, for example only with the number 22, do you mean that one specific float[] instance is filled by 22, or that all float[] instances are filled by the number 22? For example [22, 22, ..., 22], then [22, 22, ..., 22], then again [22, 22, ..., 22] etc ad infinitum?

The short version is that you need a mechanism like AutoResetEvents or a thread-safe queue between the threads like BlockingQueue or Channel. Locks and volatile aren't enough.
_readWriteValue isn't locked. The loop in Thread2 runs a lot faster than the call to ran.Next(1, 100) so the entire loop can finish before ran.Next(1, 100) had a chance to run a second time. Even if you add volatile to prevent some optimizations, _readWriteValue still has the original value while the loop is running.
This is called a race condition. The execution result depends entirely on how fast each thread is running. To fix this you need a way of synchronizing the writer, Thread1, and reader, Thread2.
This is an even trickier problem because the reader has to read all the values produced by the writer. This requires two-way synchronization between the reader and writer.
Synchronizing Reads/Writes with events
To avoid this problem, a way is needed to ensure that the reader (Thread2) can only read a value after the writer (Thread1) writes it, and that the writer can't write the value until the reader reads the previous one.
One way to do this is to use the AutoResetEvent class. Threads can wait on an AutoResetEvent class until another thread signals it. When that happens, the waiting thread continues and the event is automatically reset.
One event is used to signal that Thread1 produced a value and another that Thread2 consumed it. This snippet doesn't repeat numbers:
static readonly AutoResetEvent _thread1Step = new AutoResetEvent(false);
static readonly AutoResetEvent _thread2Step = new AutoResetEvent(true);

private static void Thread1()
{
    Random ran = new Random(100);
    while (!_stop)
    {
        
        _thread2Step.WaitOne();
        _readWriteValue = ran.Next(1, 100);
        _thread1Step.Set();
    }
}

private static void Thread2()
{
    while (!_stop)
    {
        
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
        float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
            _thread1Step.WaitOne();
            bufferData[i] = _readWriteValue;
            _thread2Step.Set();
        }
        // Print statistics
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bufferData));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

This prints
96, 16, 67, 90, 36, 94, 71, 61, 35, 15, 96, 54, 38, 50, 97, 48, 89, 99, 39, 4, 11, 38, 89, 96, 50, 84, 91, 65, 17, 62, 11, 79, 51, 50, 56, 10, 86, 53, 47, 74, 28, 50, 34, 59, 63, 86, 36, 3, 91, 44, 3, 79, 30, 86, 22, 59, 27, 70, 40, 51, 4, 7, 44, 73, 5, 17, 3, 88, 93, 88, 62, 37, 53, 64, 76, 60, 5, 30, 34, 64, 49, 88, 73, 73, 59, 32, 50, 65, 28, 97, 83, 17, 13, 95, 70, 21, 6, 60, 55, 46
83, 48, 9, 4, 82, 66, 26, 65, 10, 61, 54, 96, 36, 76, 3, 15, 33, 71, 15, 73, 67, 38, 60, 96, 6, 45, 24, 57, 94, 55, 55, 45, 75, 87, 81, 1, 79, 70, 90, 92, 6, 85, 55, 66, 44, 86, 80, 37, 93, 55, 88, 34, 46, 81, 78, 45, 87, 13, 98, 37, 42, 69, 70, 55, 7, 10, 21, 49, 94, 2, 36, 63, 80, 22, 67, 82, 83, 93, 53, 19, 65, 87, 63, 40, 67, 21, 98, 93, 9, 36, 14, 67, 72, 54, 51, 36, 15, 99, 60, 34
66, 32, 42, 91, 20, 25, 54, 25, 15, 96, 62, 93, 60, 79, 72, 55, 6, 31, 88, 85, 11, 27, 40, 58, 88, 68, 91, 27, 71, 31, 67, 83, 34, 19, 53, 33, 45, 72, 21, 42, 67, 74, 79, 13, 74, 20, 7, 92, 81, 95, 30, 84, 12, 74, 24, 39, 92, 83, 4, 51, 33, 28, 53, 83, 29, 78, 60, 42, 27, 39, 11, 34, 10, 46, 19, 36, 48, 27, 84, 68, 62, 99, 45, 75, 1, 83, 72, 59, 94, 14, 41, 61, 68, 69, 9, 39, 21, 96, 83, 96

Using a BlockingQueue works
Coupling one thread to the other like this is not always a good idea, as each one has to wait for the other to proceed. If one slows down for one reason, so does the other. One way to avoid this is to use a thread-safe queue
Using a BlockingQueue like another answer shows works with only slight modifications :
private static BlockingCollection<float> _queue=new BlockingCollection<float>(100);

private static void Thread1()
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    while (!_stop)
    {
        _queue.Add( ran.Next(1, 100));
    }
}

private static void Thread2()
{
    while (!_stop)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
        float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for(int i=0;i<BUFFER_SIZE;i++)
        {
            bufferData[i] = _queue.Take();
        }
        // Print statistics
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bufferData));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

And prints
18, 70, 21, 74, 38, 77, 75, 15, 16, 62, 97, 22, 57, 98, 37, 63, 26, 80, 47, 21, 50, 94, 7, 84, 84, 78, 11, 92, 5, 82, 37, 4, 25, 1, 21, 62, 46, 97, 83, 87, 72, 33, 99, 50, 59, 69, 33, 88, 65, 86, 55, 56, 77, 44, 6, 31, 31, 19, 13, 60, 38, 12, 67, 12, 88, 34, 18, 8, 94, 86, 26, 7, 20, 87, 32, 37, 93, 46, 82, 58, 44, 57, 89, 10, 26, 38, 51, 54, 42, 56, 16, 87, 66, 66, 79, 55, 50, 87, 18, 90
94, 37, 77, 91, 62, 12, 48, 96, 91, 12, 84, 45, 80, 5, 32, 59, 4, 72, 47, 83, 88, 74, 63, 39, 62, 28, 32, 86, 88, 38, 85, 62, 18, 84, 82, 36, 42, 81, 20, 66, 36, 30, 92, 31, 62, 54, 68, 25, 84, 67, 31, 26, 16, 15, 32, 67, 22, 33, 22, 68, 68, 55, 6, 59, 81, 18, 6, 46, 10, 33, 73, 78, 65, 37, 84, 79, 34, 34, 51, 21, 6, 51, 80, 25, 53, 30, 50, 39, 53, 5, 1, 44, 36, 70, 57, 39, 67, 24, 37, 47
43, 61, 86, 89, 87, 83, 29, 23, 24, 78, 28, 10, 39, 90, 22, 66, 23, 70, 51, 48, 83, 3, 23, 92, 29, 22, 30, 98, 96, 16, 96, 99, 71, 85, 42, 96, 47, 57, 4, 7, 98, 8, 28, 91, 38, 6, 27, 69, 93, 65, 42, 70, 22, 53, 67, 57, 36, 45, 81, 89, 63, 42, 52, 63, 59, 47, 33, 1, 66, 49, 9, 3, 46, 60, 6, 23, 76, 83, 48, 99, 61, 10, 4, 42, 22, 57, 15, 5, 9, 51, 89, 37, 40, 80, 61, 46, 56, 71, 24, 

That's because the writer, Thread1, writes all values to a thread safe queue. The reader, Thread2, reads these one by one. Using a queue with a capacity of 100 means that if the writer was faster than the reader, the values wouldn't be lost. If the collection gets full, the writer is blocked.
If you set the capacity to just 1, you effectively run both threads in lockstep.
Using CancellationToken
_stop itself needs locking. Instead of adding a lock though, it's better to use the purpose-built CancellationToken class. This is a struct that can be passed to methods that support cancellation to tell them when to cancel. Almost all .NET methods that support cancellation use CancellationToken, and that includes BlockingCollection.Take :
private static CancellationTokenSource _cts=new ();

private static BlockingCollection<float> _queue=new (100);

public static void Stop()
{
    _cts.Cancel();
}
private static void Thread1()
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    var token=_cts.CancellationToken;

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _queue.Add( ran.Next(1, 100));
    }
}

private static void Thread2()
{
    var token=_cts.CancellationToken;

    while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
        float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for(int i=0;i<BUFFER_SIZE;i++)
        {
            bufferData[i] = _queue.Take(token);
        }
        // Print statistics
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bufferData));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

The modern way: async/await
The code can be simplified a lot by using tasks, async/await and Channels, the asynchronous equivalent to BlockingCollection. This time there's no need to have any fields. The channel and tokens can be passed to a Writer and Reader function as parameters :
public static async Task Main()
{
    var  cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    var channel=Channel.CreateBounded<float>(100);

    var task1=Task.Run(()=>Writer(channel.Writer,cts.Token));
    var task2=Task.Run(()=>Reader(channel.Reader,cts.Token));
    await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
}
        

private static async Task Writer(ChannelWriter<float> writer,CancellationToken token)
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var value = ran.Next(1, 100);
        await writer.WriteAsync(value,token);
    }
}

private static async Task Reader(ChannelReader<float> reader,CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {           
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
        float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {               
            bufferData[i] = await reader.ReadAsync(token);
        }
        // Print statistics
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bufferData));
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}

The output is :
54, 38, 99, 32, 82, 40, 50, 71, 39, 84, 69, 75, 69, 91, 70, 46, 20, 82, 72, 34, 27, 26, 79, 25, 48, 28, 84, 98, 4, 39, 99, 30, 11, 28, 47, 63, 89, 27, 35, 14, 92, 84, 33, 36, 69, 55, 65, 80, 59, 24, 63, 83, 6, 79, 18, 23, 5, 72, 47, 22, 36, 89, 51, 9, 57, 16, 50, 84, 35, 97, 35, 24, 36, 38, 99, 5, 31, 16, 14, 9, 62, 51, 67, 25, 29, 61, 20, 22, 31, 58, 93, 98, 97, 5, 89, 93, 56, 58, 74, 41
7, 59, 61, 7, 19, 33, 37, 67, 57, 25, 99, 13, 80, 56, 46, 21, 2, 41, 97, 84, 11, 40, 11, 58, 12, 94, 1, 23, 79, 20, 15, 26, 40, 51, 51, 55, 42, 11, 34, 39, 5, 99, 1, 59, 5, 75, 8, 74, 93, 23, 66, 63, 41, 16, 71, 36, 88, 74, 61, 38, 63, 46, 50, 10, 26, 64, 25, 28, 28, 55, 82, 5, 80, 68, 52, 79, 37, 56, 80, 91, 67, 87, 3, 17, 87, 84, 87, 94, 55, 13, 64, 92, 60, 99, 64, 53, 72, 87, 14, 99
64, 33, 93, 29, 14, 60, 48, 40, 46, 71, 5, 96, 12, 22, 50, 49, 36, 78, 27, 95, 24, 40, 8, 45, 29, 27, 6, 33, 99, 62, 84, 85, 29, 72, 5, 79, 73, 17, 88, 92, 38, 16, 39, 49, 66, 70, 37, 99, 64, 11, 31, 61, 3, 46, 21, 3, 71, 31, 68, 87, 14, 19, 24, 80, 93, 14, 97, 90, 13, 32, 90, 64, 97, 92, 37, 49, 66, 2, 32, 93, 57, 72, 97, 4, 75, 62, 80, 17, 73, 98, 32, 43, 6, 64, 38, 92, 73, 21, 55, 65

Volatile doesn't work
Even if compiler optimizations are disabled, Thread1 generates values a lot slower than Thread2 reads them.
Compiler and CPU optimizations can rewrite the loop into code that copies the value of _readWriteValue and copy it to each location directly, perhaps even use SIMD operations to assign multiple locations at once. The volatile keyword can be used to tell the compiler to avoid such optimizations. It doesn't introduce any kind of locking.
This code, taken almost intact from one of the other answers, prints the same number repeatedly, just like your own code :
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static volatile float _readWriteValue = 0;
    private static volatile bool _stop = false;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Timer timer = new(_ => _stop = true);
        timer.Change(200, Timeout.Infinite);

        Thread t1 = new(() => Thread1());
        Thread t2 = new(() => Thread2());

        t1.Start(); t2.Start();
        t1.Join(); t2.Join();
    }

    private static void Thread1()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        while (!_stop)
        {
            _readWriteValue = ran.Next(1, 100);
        }
    }

    private static void Thread2()
    {
        while (!_stop)
        {
            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
            float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
            {
                bufferData[i] = _readWriteValue;
            }
            // Print statistics
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bufferData));
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}

Result:
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 66, 66, 66, 66
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 40, 40, 40, 40
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 22, 22, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 54, 54
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 74, 74

There are roughly 10-15 read operations for every write.
A lock alone isn't enough
The reason is the same - the threads run at different speeds and the reader will always read values faster than the writer can produce them.
This variation of the code also repeats values:
private static object _locker=new();

private static void Thread1()
{
    Random ran = new Random(100);
    while (!_stop)
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            _readWriteValue = ran.Next(1, 100);
        }
    }
}

private static void Thread2()
{
    while (!_stop)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
        float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
            lock(_locker)
            {
                bufferData[i] = _readWriteValue;
            }
        }
        // Print statistics
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bufferData));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

This prints
55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 54, 54, 54, 58, 58, 58, 58, 83, 83, 83, 53, 53, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 40, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71
43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 8, 8, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59



Do I have a wrong understanding of the multi-threading? What should I do?

Yes, it seems that you are not familiar with the concepts of memory models, memory barriers, volatility and atomicity, and probably others. If you aspire to write correct lock-free code, you must familiarize yourself with all these concepts. Which is considered to be an extraordinarily difficult task, significantly more challenging than doing multithreading under the protection of the lock statement.
Neither of the two solutions below prevent repeated values entirely. They merely make sure the reader can observe changes when the writer makes them.  If multiple read iterations complete between one write, you'll have some number of repeats.  Especially with just a volatile read (solution 2 in this answer), you'll have quite a few repeats because the reader is just doing pure loads that will hit in L1d cache until the writer invalidates it.  But with a large enough array, you'll still see different random values, and the run lengths will roughly correspond to the speed ratios in that run.
Solution 1: simple locking
The idea of locking is to interact with the mutable state of your class (the _readWriteValue and _stop fields) in protected sections of code where only one thread can enter at a time. The concept is also known as synchronization and mutual exclusion, from where the name Mutex comes from:
private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536 * 8;

private readonly object _locker = new();
private float _readWriteValue = 0;
private bool _stop = false;

private void Thread1()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        float localValue = random.Next(1, 100);
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _readWriteValue = localValue;
            if (_stop) break;
        }
    }
}

private void Thread2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_stop) break;
        }
        float[] bufferData = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
            float localValue;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                localValue = _readWriteValue;
            }
            bufferData[i] = localValue;
        }
        ProcessMethod(bufferData);
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    lock (_locker) _stop = true;
}

Notice that I used the lock to protect only the interaction with the shared state, and nothing else. Invoking the ProcessMethod is not protected, because it doesn't have to be. This method interacts only with the local bufferData argument, which is not shared with other threads. Including it in the lock would increase the lock-contention for no good reason.
It is important to use the same _locker object in all lock statements. It is also important to be careful and disciplined. A single unprotected access to the shared state of your class is enough to ruin everything and make the behavior of your program undefined.
Solution 2: lock-free with `volatile`
A lock-free solution to the problem of the number repeating forever is to declare the fields as volatile:
private volatile float _readWriteValue = 0;
private volatile bool _stop = false;

This will prevent the infinite repeating of the same number in the bufferData (demo), because the volatile keyword informs the compiler that the field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time, so it won't do optimizations that are intended for single-thread programs.
Most likely in your case the compiler optimized your code by storing the value of the _readWriteValue field in a local variable (in the thread's stack), and reused that value forever instead of looking for the actual value in the object in the heap. If you don't tell it otherwise, the C# compiler assumes that your program is single-threaded, and might do optimizations that make your program faster and more efficient. The compiler doesn't (and shouldn't) care if by doing so it wreaks havoc on multithreaded code that is not authored correctly.
To put it another way, all optimizations that are safe for single-threaded code are allowed for plain variables, which is why its a bad idea to share them without locking or volatile if some of the simultaneous accesses are writes.  So within each thread, code that isn't communicating with other threads can be fully optimized.
It will likely repeat several times, maybe hundreds depending on how slow ran.Next is; FP RNG is pretty slow compared to a load.  Once one load succeeds, later loads will hit in L1d cache until the other thread invalidates our copy as part of its Read For Ownership (RFO) to get exclusive ownership of the cache line (MESI) in order to write it.  So the reader will have bursts of progress.  Out-of-order exec and multiple load buffers probably make it even more bursty, as many loads can be queued up waiting for the next time we get a copy of the cache line.  Then all those L2 cache misses will complete at once when a copy of the line arrives to satisfy our share request.
With locking, the burst will be much shorter (in number of array elements) because each lock/unlock by the reader is much slower than a simple load and store to the array.

How will volatile prevent repeating numbers without locks? Random.Next is a lot slower than the assignments, perhaps even slower than the entire loop. The only reason the fiddle works is Thread.Sleep that evicts the thread and takes far more than 10ms to reschedule. Remove it and most iterations get repeating values. Some even get a single repeating value

@PanagiotisKanavos the volatile prevents the repetition of always the same number, which is what the OP observed and wants to be explained. The volatile informs the compiler that the field is used by multiple threads, so the compile emits instructions that always read the field directly instead of caching it's value in a local variable, and reusing that value forever. Of course it's possible that the buffer might be filled occasionally with the same number, for example if the Thread1 is suspended by the operating system for a few milliseconds while the Thread2 is running.

So you still need locks. This isn't a lock-free option. This isn't a suspension issue, the code in Thread1 is slower than the loop in Thread2, so there's always a race condition

@PanagiotisKanavos my answer contains two solutions, one using the lock and one using the volatile. I edited the answer for clarity.

I understood that from the start. volatile doesn't work and your own fiddle proves this

With volatile, instead of getting all the same number, with a large enough array you'll get runs of the same number, where the run length corresponds to the speed ratio.  Your answer should tell the OP to look for that (it might not be visible in the tooltip popup like they're showing in their screenshot; that's only about a dozen values).

Your answer makes it sound like volatile alone is going to avoid repeated values entirely.  It won't, but it's is a necessary part of a lock-free reader that repeatedly observes a shared variable like _stop or _readWriteValue.  A demo recording the values the read loop saw is interesting and helpful for understanding what's going on with threads that don't synchronize, and that this sort of thing is normal for lock-free code.

@PeterCordes I've asked the OP about this in a comment under the question. My hypothesis is that the OP is perfectly aware about the possibility of getting runs of the same number, and they expect this behavior. What they didn't expect is that all float[] buffers are containing always the same number. For example [22, 22, ..., 22], then [22, 22, ..., 22], then again [22, 22, ..., 22] etc ad infinitum. I am inclined to wait until the OP gives feedback to my comment, before making more changes to this answer (I've already made quite a lot).

@TheodorZoulias: Yeah, hopefully they know to expect that, but it would be a good idea to be a bit more explicit about what to expect, to avoid the possibility of giving the wrong impression.

@PeterCordes in case the OP responds, and my hypothesis is correct, then the question could be clarified. Which would reduce the need for clarifying further my answer, because the readers' expectations would be already adjusted accordingly.

The lock solution doesn't work either and repeats numbers. The problem isn't access to the field but the difference in speed between the threads.

@PeterCordes thanks for editing the answer. I hope that the OP is able to chew the quite technical and advanced (for the skills of the average C# developer) information that you added! :-)

This statement the volatile keyword informs the compiler that the field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time, so it won't do optimizations that are intended for single-thread programs is not quite right and it is wrong in an important way.  The C# compiler, the jitter, and the CPU are all permitted to do a variety of optimizations on volatile fields.

My rule of thumb is that if you cannot immediately see the cause of the problem that I pose here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/ then you don't understand volatile well enough to use it with confidence. (I include myself among that group of people who should not use volatile.)

@EricLippert the statement that you quoted comes from the docs: "The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. The compiler, the runtime system, and even hardware may rearrange reads and writes to memory locations for performance reasons." What gives me personally the confidence to use the volatile, is having studied the source code of the APIs in the System.Threading namespace. After lots of studying, everything clicked in place.

@EricLippert btw I've read your article, but not very recently. When I read it I was still confused. Now I am not. As an example see the comments of this recent (now deleted) answer by John Wu. I prefer to have a positive stance towards volatile, and demonstrate how it can be used successfully in practice. It is a pretty useful tool, if you know how to handle it.

Absolutely it is a useful tool! It is also a very sharp tool. My advice for people who want to use volatile is to figure out what semantics they want, and then build a type that has those semantics where volatility is an implementation detail of that type. Lazy<T> for example uses low-lock techniques internally but it presents a higher-level API to the user.

@EricLippert since you mentioned the Lazy<T>, one successful use of the volatile is an implementation of the LazyWithRetry<T>, based on the Lazy<T>. If you told me that I'd have to implement it without the volatile, I would be pretty sad. :-)

No that's definitely a thing to implement with volatile, so that users who are not experts on memory models -- like me -- can use it safely!

The example is not threadsafe. Whenever you read and write any shared values you need some form of synchronization. The compiler is allowed to essentially rewrite your example to :
     private void Thread2()
     {
         var value = _readWriteValue;
         while (!_stop)
         {
             float[] BufferData  = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
             for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
             {
                 BufferData[i] = value ;
             }
             ProcessMethod(BufferData);
         }
     }

Just adding volatile to the _readWriteValue might help with the thread safety aspect, but there are arguments when and if volatile is appropriate. Eric Lippert writes  in Atomicity, volatility and immutability are different, part three

Frankly, I discourage you from ever making a volatile field

Another alternative would be to insert memory barriers, but unless you really know what you are doing I would just recommend using a lock.
There are also a significant problem that the loops may take vastly different amounts of time to run. If you want to produce a single value that is read one time you should use queues to communicate. There are many ways to do this, but a simple way is with a blocking collection:
private BlockingCollection<float> queue = new BlockingCollection(boundedCapacity:100);
private void Thread1()
{
     Random ran = new Random();
     while (!_stop)
     {
         queue.Add( ran. Next(1, 100))
     }
    queue.CompleteAdding();
}
private void Thread2()
{
     int i = 0;
     float[] BufferData  = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
     foreach(var value in queue){
          i = (i + 1) % 10;
          BufferData[i] = value;
          if(i == 0){
              ProcessMethod(BufferData);
          }
    }
}

This uses a "bounded capacity", so that thread1 will block if there are no more space, and thread2 will block if there are no values available.

A ConcurrentQueue or a Channel would be good alternatives too.

I disagree with discouraging people from making use of the volatile keyword, when it's the best tool for what they are trying to do.

@PanagiotisKanavos Channels might be a good alternative, but I find blockingCollection (that wraps a ConcurrentQueue) vastly more useful than a plain ConcurrentQueue.

@TheodorZoulias it's not the right tool to publish data to a consumer that runs a lot faster than the producer. Random.Next is several orders of magnitude slower than a local array assignment

The OP is clearly trying to understand multithreading. The focus of their question seems to be why the same value is repeating, not how to implement correctly the producer-consumer pattern.

And volatile won't prevent repeating values

@PanagiotisKanavos: It would probably make more sense for the advice to be to avoid lock-free programming (unless you're really sure it's the right tool for the job, and you want to put in the effort to deal with the complexity required to get it right).  Telling people to avoid volatile is the opposite of helpful for people that are trying to play around with lock-free code, like the OP is.  It doesn't solve this problem on its own, but it's a necessary part of a loop that repeatedly observes a shared variable.

So instead of getting all the same number, with a large enough array you'll get runs of the same number, where the run length corresponds to the speed ratio.  Telling the OP to look for that is interesting and will help them realize and understand what's going on with threads that don't synchronize, and that this sort of thing is normal for lock-free code, and something you have to design algorithms to deal with.
